# Restlet filter on client

Tags: filter, client, restlet

I am using a restlet client to access a rest service. I have to include custom authentication before the request goes out. Is it possible to include a filter on the client side? I have seen several examples of using filter at the server end. But none on the client end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an simple example on:

https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet.example/src/org/restlet/example/tutorial/Part09b_AuthenticateClient.java

// Add the client authentication to the call

```
ChallengeScheme scheme = ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC;
ChallengeResponse authentication = new ChallengeResponse(scheme,"scott", "tiger");
resource.setChallengeResponse(authentication);
```